# What versions of Office 2016 support Office.context.reqirements.isSetSupported()?

Tags: javascript, office365api, office-js

We are running Office 2016 16.0.6741.2063 (Deferred channel), allot of the Office 365 API works fine (some issues around using docx inserts etc, but XML is fine)

But this code always goes to "blockUI and warning (if I take out (not) "!", then it is fine, so is not an error in the rest of the code).

'WordApi' in any shape or form fails (1.2, no version, 1, 0.1 - I have tried them all!)
According to the spec 2016 should support this, but it seems the deferred channel doesn't?

Any ideas of how to make this run (or any other tips  for finding office version in JavaScript)

Some of the team are on version 15..n of Office, and I am trying to use this to alert them to upgrade to 16..n to reduce the support burden!

```
        Office.initialize = function (reason) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                if (! Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', 1.1)){
                    $.blockUI({message: "This Add-In only works with versions of Office 365 greater than 16, please ring the help doesk to get your version upgraded <br/><a href='https://www.office.com/1?auth=2&home=1&from=ShellLogo'><u>Or click here for Office 365</u></a>"});
                }
                else {
                    // If setSelectedDataAsync method is supported by the host application
                    // the UI buttons are hooked up to call the method else the buttons are removed     
                    if (Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync) {             
                        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(addDocsAsYouGo, "sp.js");   
                        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(addDocsAsYouGoDefr, "sp.js");
                        if(!siteInitialised){
                            initialiseSharePointConnection();
                        }
                        if (!pathInitiliased){
                            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {           
                                filePath = oWebsite.get_serverRelativeUrl() + "/Shared Documents/addin/ContentDOCX/";
                                pathInitiliased = true;             
                            });
                        }
                    }       
                }
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All versions of the Add-in-enabled clients support this (i.e., 2013, 2016, Mac, Online, etc. etc.)  You'll have to agree that it would be rather ironic (and catch-22) to require that you know what client you're on, in order to query the API that will [effectively] tell you what client you're on.

If you're not seeing this work, **please check what version of Office.js you're using**.  The API was added in a way that retroactively makes it work for Office 2013 (which shipped without this), but you have to be using the latest (or close to) version of Office.js. Referencing the CDN would be the best way to guarantee this.

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I am using version with header info: "Version: 16.0.6207.1000" which I downloaded from the same url as you mention above, but I can  see the file has moved forward to "16.0.7111.3002" (looks like I'll need to do some regression testing!). I'll try out the latest and post back.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that worked. Do you know if it is possible to get a copy of the latest version. The app I have written is supposed to be very low maintenance, to ensure that I need to be certain the libraries don't change. So previously I hosted the Office api as well. What I want to avoid is some sudden error or failure caused by a script update (I am not tracking the changes of Office api)

Comment: Oddly enough if you create a VS Office Add-in project, using the latest version, the reference points to https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js but the auto generated code in VS adds an offline version of the api - 16.0.6207.1000 - so VS offline cannot (in theory) support Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', 1.2) ! I am going to give it a try!

Comment: Were you in offline mode when you created the project? Visual Studio will add an offline reference if it cannot reach the Internet what creating the project.

Comment: In either case, either have your html point to the online CDN, or update the Office.js Nuget package to the latest.

Comment: Michael - do you know what API is supported in Word 365 online version? The same script blocks when run in Word online, and I am unsure how to reverse the script to output the actual Office api version.

Comment: @JerryWeeks, just go ahead and query for a number of different versions.  I.e., `if (isSetSupported('WordApi', 1.1)) { console.log("1.1"); }`, then the same with 1.2 and 1.3.  Not sure what you mean by "the same script blocks" -- do you mean the same script as you're trying to use in your rich client, or the same isSetSupported script (should never block...)

Comment: When I run the check for 1.1, 1.2 etc in Word online it fails (i.e. Word online doesn't support isSetSupported('WordApi", 'n.n'). However Word online and local client does appear to support this (which is in the same _setMap). As I am mostly just appending ooxml documents, this would appear to be useful, but can I trust it?     if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("ooxmlcoercion", "1.1")) { //do something...}

Comment: I just worked my way to this Michael. On my local copy of Word I get 1.3, but on the 365 hosted online version I get "undefined"     ***showNotification("Word API is " + Office.context.requirements._setMap._sets.wordapi);***

Answer (score 1):

I found a way of extracting the "feature" list from Word API.

Using a div "id=resultpanel" for output and this piece of code gets me the feature set:

```
        Office.initialize = function (reason) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                    var sets = Office.context.requirements._setMap._sets;       
                    for (var set in sets){
                        showNotification("Set type: " + set + " value " +sets[set]  );
                    }

                //if (! Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', 1.1)) {
                //if ( Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', 1.2)){
                    // alert something
                //}
                //else {
                    // If setSelectedDataAsync method is supported by the host application
                    // the UI buttons are hooked up to call the method else the buttons are removed     
                    if (Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync) {             
                        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(addDocsAsYouGo, "sp.js");   
                        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(addDocsAsYouGoDefr, "sp.js");
                        if(!siteInitialised){
                            initialiseSharePointConnection();
                        }
                        if (!pathInitiliased){
                            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {           
                                filePath = oWebsite.get_serverRelativeUrl() + "/Shared Documents/DOCXApproved/";
                                pathInitiliased = true;             
                            });
                        }
                    }       
                //}
            });
        };

        function showNotification(content) {
            var resultpanel = document.getElementById("resultpanel");
            var currentText = resultpanel.innerHTML;
            currentText = currentText + "<br/>" + content;
            resultpanel.innerHTML = currentText;
        }
```

The output from Word on Office 365 online gives:

```
        Set type: compressedfile value 1.1
        Set type: documentevents value 1.1
        Set type: file value 1.1
        Set type: imagecoercion value 1.1
        Set type: matrixcoercion value 1.1
        Set type: ooxmlcoercion value 1.1
        Set type: pdffile value 1.1
        Set type: selection value 1.1
        Set type: settings value 1.1
        Set type: tablecoercion value 1.1
        Set type: textcoercion value 1.1
        Set type: textfile value 1.1
```

and from Word desktop client version 16.0.6741.2063 I get:

```
        Set type: compressedfile value 1.1
        Set type: customxmlparts value 1.2
        Set type: documentevents value 1.1
        Set type: file value 1.1
        Set type: htmlcoercion value 1.1
        Set type: imagecoercion value 1.1
        Set type: matrixbindings value 1.1
        Set type: matrixcoercion value 1.1
        Set type: ooxmlcoercion value 1.1
        Set type: pdffile value 1.1
        Set type: selection value 1.1
        Set type: settings value 1.1
        Set type: tablebindings value 1.1
        Set type: tablecoercion value 1.1
        Set type: textbindings value 1.1
        Set type: textcoercion value 1.1
        Set type: textfile value 1.1
        Set type: wordapi value 1.3
        Set type: wordapinewdoc value 1.2
```

Using this output I can decide which features I enable on the add-in!

Then using this I can also determine if it is Word online or desktop client

```
showNotification("url is: " + Office.context.document.url);
```

which outputs:

```
url is: https://<corp portal name>-my.sharepoint.com/personal/<my name>/Documents/Document15.docx
```

Note: ***corp portal name*** and ***my name*** will change depending on who and where it is run. Document ***nn*** .docx likewise alters (it is the auto named file added to OneDrive for business).

***On a desktop client this is blank.***